# Hide SoftKeyBoard on Android Oreo

Tags: android, android-layout, android-softkeyboard, android-8.0-oreo, android-8.1-oreo

i'm trying to prevent the keyboard from showing up after calling  requestFocus() on a SearchView but there is no solution to fix that on Android 8.

i tried :

/*1/

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"
```

/*2/

```
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

/*3/

```
InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        if (activity.getCurrentFocus() != null && activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken() != null)
            inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
```

/*4/

```
 final View activityRootView = findViewById(R.id.rootLayout);
                activityRootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onGlobalLayout() {
                        int heightDiff = activityRootView.getRootView().getHeight() - activityRootView.getHeight();
                        if (heightDiff > dpToPx(Act_StoreOrder.this, 200)) { // if more than 200 dp, it's probably a keyboard...
                            Log.i("<<<Clavier","Clavier Showed Up");
                            //hide here 
                        }
                    }
                });
```

onGlobalLayout() worked but the softkeyboard show up for nearly 0.5s and disappear.

Any help to make that softkeyboard hidden even after calling requestFocus() ??

Comment: Does the device have a hardware keyboard?  Why don't you want a keyboard when they tap on a field you type in?

Comment: because as you said i am using a hardware keyboard to fill that searchview ...

Comment: If you have an attached hardware keyboard, most software ones hide themselves.

Comment: Also, your on global layout code will fail if they use screen casting, picture in picture, or split screen apps.  Or if they use a very small keyboard like minimum.

Comment: let's forget about the hardware keyboard , how to hide the softkeyboard if there is no hardkeyboard ??

Comment: Try TextView. setShowSoftInputOnFocus(false).  Note this works only on v21+.  Although its possible the support library backports it farther (I haven't checked).

Comment: I can't use TextView because i'm using onQueryTextSubmit and onQueryTextChange of the searchView !

Comment: Check if SearchView has the same function.  If not-  I hate relying on implementation details like this, but there is an embedded TextView in the SearchView you can call it on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally i solved the problem, i just used that function bellow to intercept FocusChanges and hide the softKeyboard after 100 (enought time to intercept the softkeyboard)

```
      @Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

    if (hasFocus) {
        View lFocused = getCurrentFocus();
        if (lFocused != null)
            lFocused.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    InputMethodManager lInputManager = (InputMethodManager) pContext.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    lInputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
                }
            }, 100);//Modified to 100ms to intercept SoftKeyBoard on Android 8 (Oreo) and hide it.
    }
}
```